# FlightCrew errors for certain Amazon CSS links

Tags: kindle

I have an Amazon Ebook in which I display nature photos that I have collected. Now several years later I am updating the book with some new images.

I tried to run my update through KindlePreview and it failed. I ran Flight Crew 0.7.2 on my epub and received the following errors:

TEST-43D.epub/OEBPS/Text/Dedication.xhtml - unable to find validator for simple type of attribute 'media'

Two CSS link lines in the head section in every page receive this error report: amzn-kf8 & amzn-mobi.

I do have a "amzn-mobi.css" and "amzn-kf8.css" pages in the CSS section.

I don't remember having this problem five years ago. It appatently is causing my updated epub to fail to convert in KindlePreview.

Can anyone help an old man get beyond these problem lines reported by Flight Crew. I would like very much to get the update published.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the book with the [IDPF Validator](http://validator.idpf.org/) and add the results to your post. 

Make sure to also add the code of the lines that the validator has flagged. If it also flagged the stylesheet links, post the code for each stylesheet link.

Comment: I appreciate your response and I'd like to do it all. I've tried to show the links code and would add the CSS too, but whenever I add the HTML lines they disappear in the submission. How do I include these lines without losing them somehow in system?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll have to click the **{ }** (pre-formatted text) button to mark HTML/CSS as code.